# nginx rewrite throw 404 with last and break

Tags: yii, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a virtual host like below for my Yii website

```
server {
        root /var/www/code;
        index  index.php index.html;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        location / {
           rewrite ^/en/keyword$ /en/spesfic_controller/ last;
           ....
         }
}
```

if i use **last** or **break** in the above rewrite rule, nginx throws 404 error, but if i change it to **permanent**, it will redirect it and will work fine!! what might be wrong? or what i missed?
(nothing in error log)